# Keep Python IDLE in launcher

Tags: unity, python, launcher, .desktop, idle-python

I'd like to have an icon for Python's **I**ntegrated **D**eve**L**opment **E**nvironement (**IDLE**) in my launcher. When I've started IDLE via the dash, I can right-click on the icon and choose the 'Lock to Launcher' option. After clicking it, however, the option is still there, whereas it should have been replaced by the 'remove from Launcher' option. So, apparently, this does not work this way. Can I somehow create a custom file making a launcher icon for IDLE appear? The commands that happen when I start IDLE are

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Pavilion-13-x360-PC:~$ ps ax -f | grep python
stefan    2087  1922  0 12:30 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/glipper
stefan    3318  1751  0 13:14 ?        Sl     0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/idle3
stefan    3325  3318  0 13:14 ?        Sl     0:03 /usr/bin/python3 -c __import__('idlelib.run').run.main(True) 35780
stefan    3348  3124  0 13:19 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

so I'd somehow have to realize the two commands involving idle with a script.

**Edit:** When I type `/usr/bin/idle3` in my terminal, the other command `/usr/bin/python3 -c __import__('idlelib.run').run.main(True)` executes automatically, so there is no need to put that into some "starter" script. All the starter does is to execute `/usr/bin/idle`.

Dragging the icon from the dash directly to the launcher ([as Jacob suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672475/keep-python-idle-in-launcher/672491#672491)) keeps it in the launcher. However, after clicking it, another icon appears which is different from the starter icon and which has the defect I'm describing here. Maybe that issue can be solved as well?

Comment: Yes, that can be fixed as well, see my updated answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: It seems like the usage for the [tag:idle] tag is ambiguous, but most askers seem to use it for questions about how to get something to be done when something is *idle*.

Comment: Aaarggh, my bad, removed it... I should have known without the capital.

Comment: You were not the only one using it this way :-) Could we actually have two tags, one [tag:idle] and another one "IDLE" with capital letters?

Comment: I think it would be a great idea, Idle is widely used.

Comment: But it seems like tags are not case sensitive, I just tried to add "IDLE" to my tags here @JacobVlijm

Comment: Let me try something :)

Comment: Yes, of course, or python-idle alternatively @JacobVlijm I'll let you decide :-) I see you also added a tag-wiki to it.

Comment: I think idle-python will be found easier, and will set the difference with just "idle" (I used this definition: https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Now we just need someone to edit all the questions which used the *idle* tag wrongly, otherwise [tag:idle-python] will be almost an "idle" tag (no pun intended)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I see you've been quite busy with retagging a lot of questions. Good work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The simplest solution

Here's what you can do (simpler than you feared :) ):

- Open Dash
- Type Idle (or Idle3, depending on the version)
- Drag the icon from Dash to the Unity Launcher:

  [image]

  Then the right- click text sais:

  [image]

  (Which is Dutch for: "Remove from launcher")

#### The command to run Idle

To complete the answer: the command to run `Idle` is:

```
/usr/bin/idle
```

or for  specific version(s) e.g.: `/usr/bin/idle3`, or: `/usr/bin/idle-python3.4`

Simply look inside the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` in the line, starting with `Exec=` for the right command.

#### Prevent an extra icon from Idle when it is launched

Idle produces windows of the `WM_CLASS` "Toplevel". To make these windows appear under the same icon as you just put in th launcher, do the following:

- Copy the global `idle.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`.

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/idle.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- Open the file (drag it over an open `gedit` window).
- Add to the bottom of the file the line:

```
    StartupWMClass=Toplevel
```

- Log out and back in. From then on, all `Idle` windows will appear under one icon:

  [image]

That's it...

---

### EDIT

*As a result of the fact that windows of one `WM_CLASS` in principle only appear under one Launcher icon (at a time) in Unity, please note:*

Although the chances are practically none, grouping `Toplevel` windows under the `Idle` icon *could* show a downside in rare situations:

1. *If* you run different versions of `Idle` at the same time (e.g. editing code for two `python` versions at the same time), all windows are grouped under the icon of the version that started first:

   [image]
2. If you run `python` applications, using `tkinter` as a GUI (quite unusual these days), usually secundary windows are set as "child" of the main window by using `wm_transient()`

   In "unpolished" applications (like `Idle`), this might not be the case. In such cases, the secondary window ("Toplevel" windows in `tkinter`), will also show up under the `Idle` icon, *If* Idle ran first.

But again, normally this will probably never happen, and if it does, it does no harm but what I described.

Comment: The gets the icon to the launcher. However, when I click it, a new icon appears which is different from the starter and which has the flaw I described in my answer. So I'd call this a workaround. Anyway, +1, and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @StefanHamcke we can probably solve that as well, wait a minute...

Comment: Oh, I see, so when I type `/usr/bin/idle3` in my terminal, the other command `/usr/bin/python3 -c __import__('idlelib.run').run.main(True) 50649` "happens" automatically, so there is no need to put that into some "starter" script.

Comment: @StefanHamcke exactly. The command to run Idle is in the `.desktop` file as well.

Comment: Great! You're a genius :-)

Comment: @Stefan always fun to get things done the way you like it :)